# PHP connection Fatal Error

Tags: php

```
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, 
    object given in /home/mjcrawle/public_html/toga/homefile/processlogin.php on line 63
```

I am trying to connect a database and I am getting the above error.  I I am using 4 different includes in this file  and the include are before I try to connect to the database.

Sample of one of my includes

```
require_once('../homefile/class/database.class.php');
```

The include work fine and this is my line of code to connect my db.

```
/*New database Object*/
$db = new Database;
```

I am kind at a loss...  The database is closed.

```
mysqli_close($db);
```

There is a ton of code but I am not sure anyone would want to wade though it. If you can thing of anything let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, [`mysqli_close`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) expects the arugment to be a handle opened with `mysql_open`, but instead you've passed it a `Database` object.

Secondly, we don't know what that class contains, but I would expect that it has a method like `->close()` that closes the database connection.

Ie,

```
$db->close();
```